# Making a table-based layout resizable

Tags: javascript, html, tablelayout, resizable

I inherited a web app with a desktop-like look-and-feel. It uses tables for layout. I need to make the "panels" of the GUI resizable (like split panes).

An example of what I need to accomplish: http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/mail/ (The resizable content areas)

But instead of using divs for the layout I need to use quite complex nested tables. Is there anything out there that will let me accomplish this or will I have to convert the code to not use tables for layout?

Comment: Nested tables... yuk! Nested tables will break into your house, steal your TV and drink all your beer...

Comment: Did you try to set the width of your TD's in % ?

Comment: @Mic This is the approach at the moment, but I have a feature request to allow users to manually resize the panels by click-dragging a splitter. This question really is a last-ditch attempt before diving in and getting rid of the layout tables once and for all.

Comment: Who are they trying to impress with a web-app that looks like a desktop app?  Huh?

Comment: "quite complex nested tables" - sounds like the title of a horror movie

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING: I'm about to recommend a 3rd-party product; if that offends you, stop reading.**

If you can justify the expense of third-party software as opposed to your **time**, then I'd recommend Telerik's controls: they have a splitter that is quite fully functional. It works really well for me.

**[DEMO](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=telerik+splitter+demo&aq=1&aqi=g2&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=573da4ec7e15bdf2)**

Answer (score 0):

> ***Still, I don't mean to suggest you table layouts. If you can borrow some time safe yourself from this table mess before it start messing with you.***

Here an example of [resizable tables](http://bz.var.ru/comp/web/resizable.html). View the source of this page there you will see a inclusion of a script:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='resizable-tables.js'></script>
```

And a stylesheet:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='resizable.css' type='text/css' media='screen' />
```

And also the `!doctype` defined there is trick you should have that too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- it is transitional only because of using width='xx%' property in table example -->
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head>
```